# Postgres JSON: get the first node value without knowing the key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to get the first node value without knowing the key.

```
{"dog":"198","cat":"2835"}
```

I can return all keys with 1 per row using `json_object_keys()` but I don't want this, I want just the first node value within the json.

I want to return `198`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a62aa9649227ffa6469f9b95a755b86e)

```
WITH jsondata AS (
    SELECT '{"dog":"198","cat":"2835"}'::json as data
)
SELECT 
    value
FROM jsondata, json_each_text(data)
LIMIT 1
```

1. `json_each_text` expands all element into one row each with two columns `key` and `value` as types `text` (if you like you could convert this text into an integer)
2. `LIMIT` the output to the first one

---

**Notice**: Normally there is no "first" element in a JSON object. The order of the elements is not fix. The object `{"a":1, "b":2}` equals `{"b":2, "a":1}`. So it could be possible that you are getting any of both values. It could be completely random. E.g. in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=abc280efc5cc36fd2326070696f0099a) I am not converting into type `json` but type `jsonb`. And this gives out the `cat`. So it depends on internal states which one is selected as "first".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `row_number` window function get first key in CTE then use [->](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad993/15) get the value.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col json
);

insert into t values ('{"dog":"198","cat":"2835"}');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with getFirstKey as(
    SELECT keys FROM (
      SELECT keys,row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn
      FROM (
        SELECT col,json_object_keys(col) keys
        FROM T
      ) t1
    ) t1
    where rn = 1
)

SELECT col::json->(select keys from getFirstKey)
FROM T;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad993/15/0)**:

```
| ?column? |
|----------|
|    "198" |
```

Comment: This won't work because I don't know the first key name. Each row within the DB will have a different order of JSON nodes.